# FTDI usb to serial cable causing other USB devices to freeze

Tags: windows, ftdi, usbserial

When an FTDI serial to USB cable is plugged into either my docking station, USB hub, or directly in laptop, other USB devices periodically freeze (such as mouse and keyboard). If I plug my mouse an keyboard directly into the laptop USB ports, they do not freeze while FTDI is connected anywhere (hub, dock, or laptop), but if mouse is plugged into an indirect USB port (hub or dock) while the FTDI is connected anywhere, the mouse periodically freezes. The freezing frequency increases and for longer duration when the FTDI is connected to an embedded device.

I have tried reinstalling all hub usb drivers in device manager, deleting and installing the latest FTDI drivers, trying different USB hubs/docking stations, but nothing is working.